# systemctl from inside docker container fails with D-Bus connection error

Tags: sockets, docker, opensuse, systemctl

I have setup a docker container based on OpenSuse 12, installed some additional files and copied some installer binaries into the container. So far everything fine.

From inside a running image of the container I now need to run the aforementioned  setup program but this needs to have uuid.socket up and running - uuid.socket in turn needs systemctl to work correctly and this causes an error like this:

```
hxehost:/usr/sap/SRCFiles # systemctl
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
```

I started the docker container like this:

```
docker run -h hxehost -i -t f3096b0aa964 /bin/bash
```

Which, according to some postings should start a machine container as opposed to an application container.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here??? How do I get systemctl to work inside a docker container?

I tried to starte the container with this command, which according to linked hints should do, but to no avail

```
docker run --privileged --rm -ti -e 'container=docker' -h hxehost --network="bridge" --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro siliconchris/hxe:v0.0.2 /bin/bash
```

If I do this, systemctl still gives exact same error.

If I start **/sbin/init** instead of /bin/bash, I can see that quite a lot of services are started (some, like wicked, login and module, fail). In the end, the container presents me with a login. After login, I can now execute systemctl and it shows all services with their respective states.

Now my next question is: ***IS THIS APPROACH FEASIBLE AT ALL???***

Best regards,

Chris

You may find the repo to this image at [SAP HANA Express Edition inside docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/siliconchris/hxe/)

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7459 and https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/25567

Comment: Hey user2915097, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm probably too noob on docker to follow along as I don't get it. The linked entries talk about running the container in a specific way, which I did like so:      docker run --privileged --rm -ti -e 'container=docker' -h hxehost --network="bridge" --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro siliconchris/hxe:v0.0.2 bin/bash       Now this doesn't solve the issue. Still systemctl fails with exact same error. I will update my question text accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Most current Linux systems depend on SystemD running, and systemctl will send requests to it. However most applications did install easily when I replaced the systemctl binary with a script that just interprets start/stop/status/enable commands. As another benefit, it would not need anymore those complicated startup-commands for the resulting image to get the systemd mapped into the container. May be that would help you? Please have a look at the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement).